# Zeitwerk needs to reload every change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reload, autoload, zeitwerk

In development enviroment, when using zeitwerk, every change in ruby code needs to restart the server, because zeitwerk isn't loading classes defined in mygem. I have a gem, used by my company that uses rails models. And some of that models are reopened, and we add some methods.

I have the following model in my app.

```
require_dependency("#{Mygem::Engine.root.join('app','models','identification.rb')}")

class Identification
  include Cacheable
  has_paper_trail

  def some method
  end
end
```

And the following model in mygem, path of my gem app/models/identification.rb:

```
class Identification < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'pub_identification'

  belongs_to :city, foreign_key: 'idcity'
end
```

But if I change anything in my code, I need restart my server, because model from my gems aren't reopened. I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `has_paper_trail' for Identification:Class
```

The `has_paper_trail` method is a method from mygem. And it only works if I restart. Any tips for this?

EDIT:

Gem Structure:

```
mygem/
├─ app/
│  ├─ models/
├─ config/
├─ lib/
```

Comment: It seems `require_dependency` breaks everything https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#delete-require-dependency-calls

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right. I followed the link posted by Xavier Noria, and it works.

Comment: I am sure it is :) Xavier is the author Zeitwerk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two files defining the same constant in the autoload paths.

Your engine defines a model, and the application wants to decorate it. For this use case, please have a look at [this documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers).

Comment: it works! thanks so much. I follow that same steps and everything works fine.